# Pygame_menu loop overrides the transition to another screen

Tags: python, pygame

Currently working on a backgammon game with eventual multiplayer support.
I have a mainmenu function that is working, and its exceptions and draws are handled by the mainloop() attribute. However, I have a button that, when pressed, should switch to the game with the backgammon board as the background.
The image appears briefly, then the main menu continues to run. I've tried to find ways to disable the menuloop using conditional statements to no avail.
Here is the full source code:

```
import sys, pygame, os, pygame_menu

width, height = 1280, 960

class mainBackgammonGame():
    global width, height
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Bootleg Backgammon")
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    def updateScreen(self):
        self.clock.tick(60)
        pygame.display.flip()

    def startGame():
        surface = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
        currPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        boardPath = os.path.join(currPath, "images/mainboard.png")
        boardImage = pygame.image.load(boardPath)
        surface.blit(boardImage, (0,0))
        pygame.display.flip()

def mainMenu():
    surface = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
    menu = pygame_menu.Menu(960, 1280, 'Welcome to Backgammon', theme = pygame_menu.themes.THEME_DARK)
    menu.add_text_input("Your Name:   ", default = "Joseph Smith")
    menu.add_button('Play', mainBackgammonGame.startGame)
    menu.add_button('Quit', pygame_menu.events.EXIT)
    menu.mainloop(surface)

bg = mainBackgammonGame()

mainMenu()

while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event == pygame.QUIT:
                exit()
    bg.updateScreen()
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
def mainMenu():
    def disable():
        menu.disable()
        mainBackgammonGame.startGame()
    surface = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
    menu = pygame_menu.Menu(960, 1280, 'Welcome to Backgammon', theme = pygame_menu.themes.THEME_DARK)
    menu.add_text_input("Your Name:   ", default = "Joseph Smith")
    menu.add_button('Play', disable)
    menu.add_button('Quit', pygame_menu.events.EXIT)
    menu.mainloop(surface)
```

Added a new function within the main menu function that initially disables the menu, then will call the startGame function that loads the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading the following example:

https://github.com/ppizarror/pygame-menu/blob/master/pygame_menu/examples/game_selector.py

You can see that the main part of that is having a main menu variable

```
main_menu: Optional['pygame_menu.Menu'] = None
```

Which gets initialized elsewhere in the code.

Additionally when it's time for that menu to leave, like if you want to move to the game after being in the menu then you want a function like this:

```
def start_game():
    global menu
    # Do stuff here
    menu.disable()
```

Then in your pygame main loop you can guard the `mainloop` call like so:

```
if menu.is_enabled():
    menu.mainloop(screen)
```